# CPP error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cpp

Tags: c++, external, symbols, lnk2019

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Sounds::soundBox(void)" (?soundBox@Sounds@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

For some reason i get this error, and i rly dont know what i did wrong.
Got wimm.lib added playsound works when called from main()
When i try to call it from class in playsound.cpp it calls error...

playsounds.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class Sounds
{
public:
Sounds();
~Sounds();

void soundBox();
};
```

playsound.cpp

```
#include "playsound.h"

Sounds::Sounds()
{

}

void soundBox()
{
PlaySound(TEXT("fx/boom1.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}


Sounds::~Sounds()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "playsound.h"    

int main()
{
Sounds newsound;

newsound.soundBox();

_getch();
}
```

Comment: In the link that @πάντα ῥεῖ posted, look [specifically here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/2296458)

Comment: The weird thing is, you're already doing it correctly for `Sounds::Sounds()` and `Sounds::~Sounds()`, were these generated by your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the function definition in `playsound.cpp`

```
void soundBox()
```

To

```
void Sounds::soundBox()
```

This is because the function exists within the scope of the `Sounds` class, so you have to define it as such. Otherwise it would be a free function, and the version of the function in your `Sounds` class would be undefined (which is what the error is telling you).

Comment: Thx man, i was doing this but in header... this explains everything.